# how to add a route to swagger-ui

Tags: backbone.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I've been trying to add a route (health check) to swagger-ui. But haven't been able to figure out what is going on?

I added a routes object to SwaggerUi.js:

```
routes: {
  'health': 'health'
},

health: function() {
  return "OK";
}
```

And to the index.html file in src/main/html

I added: `window.swaggerUi.on('route:health', function() { log('here'); });`

But when I navigate to /health it could not GET. Has anyone done anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because swagger-UI is just raw HTML that serves up JS.